# Find and return matched string from List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of string and gridview rows where I need to find if row contains any of the string from my list and return the matched string.

This is my list sample:

```
List<string> lstFind = new List<string>() { "TXT1", "TXT2", "TXT3", "TXT4" };
```

Then I need to check if row contains any of the string from my list above, something like...

```
lstRemovecol.Any(row["Item code"].ToString()
```

How do I accomplish that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
lstRemovecol.Any(x=> x == row["Item code"].ToString())
```

or

```
lstRemovecol.Any(x=> x.Equals( row["Item code"].ToString()) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your recomendation

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an exact match, you just need:

```
bool found = lstRemovecol.Contains(row["Item code"].ToString());
```

No need for LINQ at all, or `Any`.

If you're trying to find any of the items within a longer string (for example, if the entry was "This is TXT1 that you should find", you'd want something like:

```
string code = row["Item code"].ToString(); // Or use a cast
bool found = lstRemovecol.Any(item => code.Contains(item));
```